# Adding "All" to a column in Spark dataframe before group by

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, union

I am trying to add a category of "all" to a column in a datframe , which i am achieving by doing this

```
df2=df1.withcolumn('Column1',lit('all'))
# Union the dataframe
Df_union1=df2.union(df1)

# Adding all to another column 
Df_union2=Df_union1.withcolumn('column2',lit('all'))
Df_union_column2=Df_union2.union(Df_union1)
.
.
.
.
.


# grouping the dataframe
Unions_all.groupby(['column1','column2']).....
```

Since i have to do this for a lot of column because i want the combination of all permutations, hence have to a lot of unions, was just wondering if there is a better or more clever way of achieving the same

In Json World i have seen people do something like

```
attribute1=['column1','all']
attribute2=['column2','all']
```

Taking the `itertools.product`  of attribute1 and attribute2

Thanks !

Comment: Adding all to multiple dataframe columns or multiple columns in a single dataframe??

Comment: @smart_coder Adding all to multiple columns single dataframe and uniouing them one by one  , since we want group by for all the possible combinations 
For example 
Column1 =[ Column1, "All"]
Column2 =[ Column2, "All"]
Column3 =[ Column3, "All"]
...... so on , 
Finally groupbyElemennt =[Column1,Colum2,Column3.....]

Comment: Can you update it in dataframe in your question

Comment: Sure , Let me update and let me know if thats wha you want